# C++ class - initialization list - recursion - passing by value

Tags: c++, memory

I have created a StateNode class which is not making a copy of itself when I try to pass by value. During the running of my algorithm I receive a 'segmentation fault' error, which is been caused by the StateNode class, once it is being passed to the recursive function. However the 'segmentation fault' only occurs on about the 10,000 call, making me think it is some sort of stack overflow. The history node gets to be a size of 10,000. Both this and the size attribute, are continuously increasing. Making it appear that all function calls are modifying the same data rather than making copies and keeping local data. As the both attributes reach a size impossible with data not been copied correctly.

Here is a template of its declaration and constructors

```
// State node, contains all current node information


class StateNode {

    public:
        StateNode();
        ~StateNode();
        StateNode(const StateNode &n2);
        void operator = (const StateNode &n2);

           ....
           ....

        double size = 3.0;

           ....

        vector<double> history;

};

StateNode::StateNode(){

}

StateNode::~StateNode(){

}

StateNode::StateNode(const StateNode &n2){

    size = n2.size;

    ....
    ....

    history = n2.history;

    ....

}

void StateNode::operator = (const StateNode &n2){

    size = n2.size;

    ....
    ....

    history = n2.history;

    ....

}
```

Here is a template of the algorithm. It is a basic recursive algorithm. To confirm I have checked to ensure it is not in an infinite loop. I think the problem is to do with my constructors. And I may need to use an initialization list? But I am unsure if this is the correct step.

```
double transverse(StateNode node){

       if (......){

           return value;

       }

       if (......){

           return transverser(node);

       }

       
       if (.....){

           return transverser(node);

       }


       else{

           node2 = node;
           return transverse(node2);
       }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the space between code blocks ... it's hard to read your code.

Comment: @Cigen, sorry I made a typo when felling into stack-overflow. It is now changed to what it actually is.

Comment: Ian, your code is very hard to read as it is. You asked a question and I think you should make the code involved comprehensible - for your sake. You are the one asking.

Comment: One comment is that you don't need to overload `operator =` if you meant to create a copy ctor. `StateNode::StateNode(const StateNode &n2)` would be called when you were doing `node2 = node`. However I don't think that's the reason you code doesn't work.

Comment: Also it might help if you post exactly how your recursion works

Comment: @Ranoiaetep, sorry about the brevity put the program is 500-600 plus lines. I think the issue is that I have three classes, with each one nested inside each other. When any of the copy constructors call one of the other copy constructors, it appears not to do so, and calls its default constructor.

Comment: Or it is possible that the default copy constructor for a vector is calling the default constructor rather than the copy constructor is the classes in the vectors

Comment: @IanKennedy Instead of having us guessing: Make a [mcve] and there's a much higher probability that you'll get an answer that you can use to fix whatever the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should read on the [Rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). As you don't manually manage any resource you shouldn't have any user defined copy ctor, copy assign and destructor.

I see nothing wrong with your code. The seg fault is probably caused by the high level of recursion deep.

Comment: Somewhere my copy or assignment constructors had been implemented incorrectly. I think probably when copying a vector of instances of a custom classes. Removing these solved my problem.